# How to convert human readable price to sqrtPriceX96 to lowest decimal price in JS for uniswap?

Tags: uniswap, uniswapv3

**Overview:**

I'm trying to convert the sqrtPriceX96 to lowest decimal price and back. Lowest decimal meaning fixed point.

**Use case:**

The reason I'm doing this is to compute whether the sqrtPriceX96 has passed a certain amount of slippage. So for example is the sqrtPriceX96 passed represents 1900, price is 1850 and I want to see if that price is more than 3% from true price, the only way to calculate this is in lowest decimal form.

**Example:**

So for example let's say I'm using the USDC-WETH pool on arbitrum where token1 is USDC and token0 is WETH. This is contrary to the ethereum where the opposite is the case.

Since USDC is token1 the price is already in how much USDC is needed for 1 WETH which is helpful, otherwise I would need to invert my price before calculating the sqrtPriceX96.

Human readable price passed is 1910, sqrtPriceX96 from 1910 is 3435251266287076101164716, and I need to convert price back from sqrtPriceX96 but this time in lowest decimal form for highest precision.

When I'm converting from human readable to sqrtPriceX96 I'm also accounting for lowest decimal form like so:

```
    const lowestDecimalPrice = new bn(price)
      .multipliedBy(new bn(10).pow(token1Decimals))
      .dividedBy(new bn(10).pow(token0Decimals));
    return BigNumber.from(
      lowestDecimalPrice
            .sqrt()
            .multipliedBy(new bn(2).pow(96))
            .integerValue(3)
            .toString()
    )
```

Then I'm trying to convert back like so for lowest decimal ratio

```
  const lowestDecimalRatio = sqrtPriceX96
    .pow(BigNumber.from("2"))
    .div(BigNumber.from("2").pow(BigNumber.from("96")));
```

My issue here is that this returns 0. Why is this?

Unfortunately the uniswap sdk has no examples of this, the faq in discord also does not, and there is no solidity equivalent either provided that I can find.

This article has been very helpful: https://blog.uniswap.org/uniswap-v3-math-primer

Comment: The rule of thumb is that the multiplication must precede division when operating with integers (as BigNumber's are). So you'd multiply with 2^96 before correcting for the number of decimals. All in all, it's a very messy computation since you also need to take the sqrt at some point, and price can be below 1.0, it's not a good idea to make a BN out of it directly.